# Weird issue where background color of website section doesn't match the background color of video on different screens

Tags: css, video, colors, shopify, background-color

We need help figuring out how to make the background color of a website section always match the background color of an autoplay video in that section so that you can't notice the edges of the video frame. You can view a preview of our dev theme here: https://qxxl5la95g7ww2x8-8535375951.shopifypreview.com , it's the video of the device floating and rotating on the 4th section.

We are using the same hex code as the video background color, and it works for the screen you are editing it on, but when you view the website on different screens (mac vs pc, desktop vs mobile), the colors don't match. Any solution for this problem would be greatly appreciated!

[image: Example of correct color matching]
[image: Example of mismatching colors on different screen]

Comment: On all devices i have the problem is visible. Color picker also says that you're not using the same hex code as the video background.

Comment: I altered the background-color using dev tools to what color picker reckoned the video background was and it looked fine. The value color picker gave me was rgb(203,243,254), this is not the background-color you have set.